# ValueError When Plotting With Partial Dependence Using Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried to follow the example from [Scikit-Learn site](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_partial_dependence_visualization_api.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-partial-dependence-visualization-api-py)

```py
print(__doc__)

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence

boston = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = boston.target

tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()
mlp = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100),
                                 tol=1e-2, max_iter=500, random_state=0))
tree.fit(X, y)
mlp.fit(X, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.set_title("Decision Tree")
tree_disp = plot_partial_dependence(tree, X, ["LSTAT", "RM"])
```

But I got an error

```
Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection\partial_dependence.py in convert_feature(fx)
    523             try:
--> 524                 fx = feature_names.index(fx)
    525             except ValueError:

ValueError: 'LSTAT' is not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2bdead960e12> in <module>
     23 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
     24 ax.set_title("Decision Tree")
---> 25 tree_disp = plot_partial_dependence(tree, X, ["LSTAT", "RM"])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection\partial_dependence.py in plot_partial_dependence(estimator, X, features, feature_names, target, response_method, n_cols, grid_resolution, percentiles, method, n_jobs, verbose, fig, line_kw, contour_kw)
    533             fxs = (fxs,)
    534         try:
--> 535             fxs = [convert_feature(fx) for fx in fxs]
    536         except TypeError:
    537             raise ValueError('Each entry in features must be either an int, '

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection\partial_dependence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    533             fxs = (fxs,)
    534         try:
--> 535             fxs = [convert_feature(fx) for fx in fxs]
    536         except TypeError:
    537             raise ValueError('Each entry in features must be either an int, '

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection\partial_dependence.py in convert_feature(fx)
    524                 fx = feature_names.index(fx)
    525             except ValueError:
--> 526                 raise ValueError('Feature %s not in feature_names' % fx)
    527         return int(fx)
    528 

ValueError: Feature LSTAT not in feature_names
```

Did I do something wrong or the tutorial is not working anymore?. I have tried to plot the partial dependency on my random forest model but got the same error.

Any bits of help is appreciated

Update: All of the error logs

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed error log please. Your example is running fine for me using Python3.

Comment: @Fourier Sorry for the lack of information. I have updated it

Comment: I am running 0.22.1 of `sklearn` and it runs without any problem. I can reproduce your error when `X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names).as_matrix()`

Comment: @Fourier I updated to sklearn 0.22.1 then it works.. Please write your answer, so I can choose it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something going wrong with `sklearn`. Please update to the most recent version (0.22.1). Your code runs flawlessly with this version.

A little side note: add `ax` to the function call of `plot_partial_dependence` to assign the ax object:

```
tree_disp = plot_partial_dependence(tree, X, ["LSTAT", "RM"], ax=ax)
```